# Http response 200 1033

Tags: django, http, httpresponse

I'm writing an application in Django. I can't find any sources where the following response codes are explained. I know that 200 stands for OK, but what about those numbers on the right? What do they mean?

"GET /people HTTP/1.1" 200 1033

"GET /people HTTP/1.1" 200 946

"GET /people HTTP/1.1" 200 1031

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GET /people HTTP/1.1" 200 1033` 
Here `1033` is the `Content-Length` of the HTTP request.

More info about `Content-Length` you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length).